# How to read the Fields:{} content inside a JSON result using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, datasnap

I'm fresh to this whole JSON and JQuery thing, and I'm trying to read a JSON structure coming from Delphi datasnap, e.g :

```
{"result":[[{"type":"VOMesas.TMesas","id":1,"fields":{ "FUsers":1,"FEnclosing":0,"FClientName":"","FCode":100,"FStatus":1,"FTotalValue":128.25}}]]}
```

How can I read it with JQuery, more especifically the Fields:{...} content ?

EDIT :

here is the function im trying to do

```
 function getContent(order) {
       $.getJSON("query.json",
    function(data) {
        $.each(data.result, function(i, item) {

        var grid = '<table border="1">';

        for (var i=0; i < item.length; i++){
            CAMPO = item[i];

            ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're loading the data via `jQuery.ajax` or similar and it's being returned with the correct MIME type (or you tell `jQuery.ajax` that what you're getting back is JSON), then what you receive in the `success` callback will be a deserialized object (no longer JSON, but the objects that the JSON described). That being the case, you just access the properties of the object, e.g.:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function(data) {
        var fields = data.result[0][0].fields;
    }
});
```

`data` being the variable pointing to the object, which has a `result` property that's an array with only one entry (so, entry `[0]`), which is itself another array with exactly one entry (so, entry `[0]` again), which is an object with a property called `fields`. Pictorially:

```
{                                        // <== data
    "result": [                          // <== data.result
        [                                // <== data.result[0]
            {                            // <== data.result[0][0]
                "type": "VOMesas.TMesas",
                "id": 1,
                "fields": {              // <== data.result[0][0].fields
                    "FUsers": 1,
                    "FEnclosing": 0,
                    "FClientName": "",
                    "FCode": 100,
                    "FStatus": 1,
                    "FTotalValue": 128.25
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

If you're retrieving the data some other way and it's still a string, you can deserialize it using [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON):

```
var data = $.parseJSON(str);
```

...and then do the above to access `fields`.

Comment: Ty, i'll try it. But just one question, jQuery.parseJSON( json ) receives a JSON structure, correct ? And if this is structure is coming from a File/URL ?

Comment: @Tutch: I think it doesn't matter. As long as you supply a `well-formed` JSON string, `parseJSON` will parse it correctly.

Comment: @Tutch: `jQuery.parseJSON` accepts a **string**. The string would contain text in JSON notation. If you're loading the JSON from a URL, the `ajax` example is more relevant. If the endpoint you're calling to get the JSON serves it correctly (with the correct MIME type), jQuery will deserialize it for you. If the MIME type is wrong, you can force it with the `dataType` option. If you're using **[JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP)** rather than JSON, be sure to tell jQuery that.

Comment: Even so, i can't do it. Let me show you the function:   post edited

Comment: @Tutch: Assuming `CAMPO` is meant to refer to the object with `type`, `id`, `fields`, and such on it, that code is fine except you're re-declaring `i` unnecessarily and aren't declaring `CAMPO` at all (the former is harmless, the latter leaves you falling prey to *[The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)*). But if you clean it up a bit, it works fine: http://jsbin.com/osivaw

Comment: Yes, it should. Problem is the code shows the all the variables as 'undefined' when I show the grid later on...

Comment: @Tutch: Then you'll have to quote the code creating the grid, probably in a separate question as the question you asked (how do I access these fields?) has actually been answered, even if it wasn't quite the question you now realize you have to ask. :-) (That happens to me sometimes, too.) My guess is you're having trouble with the asynchronous nature of `getJSON`, or you're having an issue with how closures work, but without seeing the code it's pointless to speculate...

Comment: Ha, quite. Thank you for all the help, I'll continue working on with it ! :)

Comment: Not a clue . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180622/showing-content-of-json-result-and-undefined-in-a-grid.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a string of JSON, simply use `JSON.parse` to turn it into a Javascript object.

```
var datasnap = '{"result":[[{"type":"VOMesas.TMesas","id":1,"fields": FUsers":1,"FEnclosing:0,"FClientName":"","FCode":100,"FStatus":1,"FTotalValue":128.25}}]]}';
var data = JSON.parse(datasnap);
var fields = data['result'][0]['fields'];
```

By aware, however, that the JSON you've pasted into your question is invalid:

```
{
    "result": [
        [
            {
                "type": "VOMesas.TMesas",
                "id": 1,
                "fields": FUsers":1,"FEnclosing: 0, //unbalanced "
                "FClientName": "",
                "FCode": 100,
                "FStatus": 1,
                "FTotalValue": 128.25
            }
        } //unbalanced }
    ]
]
}
```

Comment: There are two brackets behind "result", so you'll have to use two successive array indexes instead of one

Answer (score 0):

First: Let's assume you assigned your JSON object to a variable "myobject". Then you can do

```
var myfields = myobject.result[0][0].fields;
```

Comment: JavaScript object, not JSON object. Once it's been deserialized into an object graph, it has nothing to do with JSON, which is a *textual* notation (like source code).

Comment: ok I can agree that JSON is just a textual notation for the object (which is exactly what JSON literally means). So it is the same difference as between you as a person and your name. But I will always call you with your name and it's still you reacting :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code example will help you to understand the jQuery/JSON thing.

I have taken the sample JSON object as an array. Then populating small HTML by reading key/value pair of JSON.

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/WC84k/