# Showing content of JSON result and 'undefined' in a grid

Tags: jquery, json, grid

So, I'm using JQuery to read a JSON and put it inside a grid. Problem is : the grid won't show when the JSON is :

```
{"result":[[{"type":"VOMesas.TMesas","id":1,"fields":{ "FUsers":1,"FEnclosing":0,"FClientName":"","FCode":100,"FStatus":1,"FTotalValue":128.25}}]]}
```

But if the JSON is like that, without the field:{...} :

```
{"result":[[{"type":"VOMesas.TMesas","id":1,"FUsers":1,"FEnclosing":0,"FClientName":"","FCode":100,"FStatus":1,"FTotalValue":128.25}]]}
```

It reads.

Here is the function I'm using:

```
function getContent(order) {
    $.getJSON("query.json", function(data) {
        $.each(data.result, function(i, item) {

            var grid = '<table border="1">';

            var i=0;

            var CAMPO;

            for (i=0; i < item.length; i++){
                CAMPO = item[i];


                grid += '<tr><td>'+ CAMPO.FQtdPessoas +
                        '</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FDataFechamento +
                        '</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FTempoPermanencia +
                        '</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FNomeCliente +
                        '</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FValorAcrescimo +
                        '</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FValorDesconto +
                        '</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FValorServico +
                        '</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FDataAbertura +
                        '</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FNumero +
                        '</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FStatus +
                        '</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FValorTotal +
                        '</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FTerminalAberto +
                        '</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FNumeroVenda +
                        '</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FGarcon +
                        '</td></tr>';
            }
            grid += '</table>'; 

            $("#dvContent").html(grid);
            $("#dvContent").find("a").click(function(e){
                var link = $(this);
                getContent(link.html());
            });
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {
getContent();
});
});
```

Comment: The part you've omitted where you have `........` is almost certainly highly relevant. :-)

Comment: The code is : grid += '<tr><td>'+ CAMPO.FQtdPessoas +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FDataFechamento +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FTempoPermanencia +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FNomeCliente +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FValorAcrescimo +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FValorDesconto +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FValorServico +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FDataAbertura +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FNumero +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FStatus +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FValorTotal +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FTerminalAberto +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FNumeroVenda +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FGarcon +'</td></tr>'; which is the fields real content.

Comment: You asked the same question twice and you hadn't answer it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179397/how-to-read-the-fields-content-inside-a-json-result-using-jquery, please mark you the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in the code you're omitting:

`grid += '<tr><td>'+ ........ +'</td></tr>';`

If the json result is in the first format, then you should be able to access the `fields` object using `CAMPO.fields`.

**Edit:**

Example:

```
grid += '<tr><td>'+ CAMPO.fields.FQtdPessoas +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.fields.FDataFechamento +'</td><td>'+ [...]
```

Comment: The code is :
     
    grid += '<tr><td>'+ CAMPO.FQtdPessoas +'</td><td>'+    CAMPO.FDataFechamento +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FTempoPermanencia +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FNomeCliente +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FValorAcrescimo +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FValorDesconto +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FValorServico +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FDataAbertura +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FNumero +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FStatus +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FValorTotal +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FTerminalAberto +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FNumeroVenda +'</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FGarcon +'</td></tr>';

 which is the fields real content.

Comment: Thank you very much :) ! It worked like a charm. I tried to do it, but had forgotten one of the field{} fields xD

Answer (score 0):

For using properties under **field** use:

```
item.result[0][0].fields.<<Your proprerties here>>
```

For the **Id** and **Type** do:

```
item.result[0][0].id
item.result[0][0].type
```

Edit:

```
for (i = 0; i < item.result.length; i++) {
            CAMPO = item.result[i][i].fields;
             grid += '<tr><td>'+ CAMPO.FQtdPessoas +
                    '</td><td>'+ CAMPO.FDataFechamento +'</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: I recommend using the *debugger* key, coz this will give you the ability to discover or explore for more information about objects attributes in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `CAMPO` refers to the object that looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "VOMesas.TMesas",
    "id": 1,
    "fields": {
        "FUsers": 1,
        "FEnclosing": 0,
        "FClientName": "",
        "FCode": 100,
        "FStatus": 1,
        "FTotalValue": 128.25
    }
}
```

To access its fields, use the `fields` property (or set `CAMPO` to `item[i].fields`).